# can a single lambda function perform more than one task?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Can a single Lambda function be used to first get files from ec2 instance based on a paticular paramaeter and if the files satisfy the given parameters then move them to a s3 bucket?

Comment: It can perform as many tasks as possible during defined execution time. A Lambda function can run for up to [15 minutes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).

Comment: ok . You mean that  single function can also connect to more than one aws resources., and also program accordingly on the listed resources? @A.Khan

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: thanks for the help mate. i will try for the same and update accordingly.@A.Khan